# Why does only the last input appear in the text file?

Tags: python

I want to add a name and a phone number to a file named `contacts.txt`

```
# ... previous code
number = raw_input("Choose a number: ")
if int(number) == 1:
    name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
    with open('contacts.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(name)
    no = raw_input("Enter phone number: ")
    with open('contacts.txt','w') as g:
        g.write(no)
```

After entering a name and a number, only the number appeared in the text file.

> Enter name: sam
>
> Enter phone number: 69

Output in `contacts.txt`:

> 69

Why doesn't my name appear?

I also added another raw_input (so I now have 3) and only the last input got written.

Comment: `'w'` means write. You are overwriting the content with the phone number

Comment: @LPK oh. then how can I add anything to the file?

Comment: Change it to `'a'` for append as the answer already suggested

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file twice, each time writing from its beginning. It's because you open the file in `'w'` (write) mode.

Either open the file just once, or open it in append mode (`'a'`) the second time.